# Neo4j Graph Query for Specified Period

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, cypher

I am learning Neo4j graph and not able extract data for following scenario.

I have following sample graph:
[image]

In this graph there is relationship between Customer and Company. I would like know two things from graph:
1. Relationships of Customer between different company for specified period.
2. Period slots where there is no relationship with Customer.

```
e.g. For Period 01-04-2018 to 31-03-2019
Result will be :
1. having relationship
Customer,Company,Start_Date,End_Date
Customer, Company A, 01-05-2018,30-06-2018
Customer, Company B,01-08-2018,01-09-2018
2. not having any relationship(for period 01-04-2018 to 31-03-2019)
Customer,Start_Date,End_Date
Customer,01-04-2018,30-04-2018
Customer,01-07-2018,31-07-2018
Customer,02-09-2018,31-03-2019
```

I am using latest Neo4j 3.3.2. I am not able find query or code using Spring data for the above requirement.

Please help me to extract this data.

Comment: *All* the sample date ranges (including the ones in section 2) overlap the period of April 1, 2018 through March 31, 2019. Can you clarify what you are looking for?

Comment: Actually I would like to know for what period particular customer is mapped to any company or not. E.g. Insurance company and customer, I would like to know for any period is customer remains without insurance? If insured then for what period and from which company?

Comment: That sounds like a completely different question. Can you edit your question accordingly? Otherwise, the answer will not match the question. Also, are you importing data from a CSV file? If so, show info on the file. In general, provide more details about what you actually have to work with.